# (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) crashes on pre-release Android device

Tags: android, sensormanager

As title says,

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

crashes on pre-release Android tablet. SENSOR_SERVICE is defined as "sensor" and things look good in other respects. Pre-release device is very close to release, fwtw.

I am wondering if there are some permissions files that might be missing in /system/etc/permissions or if I need to specify some uses-permission values in manifest or ???

I will be running test app on another (ASUS) tablet to help isolate problem. But any helpful insights are welcome.

Comment: Believe something broke in firmware level....

Comment: turns out that I was making call in constructor for my subclass. moving call to onCreate() fixed problem.